# terraform - AWS VPC change the default security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, security-groups, terraform

How do i edit the ingress and egress and also the tags of the default security group within AWS VPN created by Terraform

What i have tried:

```
 resource "aws_security_group" "default" {
   name        = "default"
   description = "default VPC security group"
   vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"
   tags {
    Name = "Do Not Use"
  }
}
```

But i keep getting:
**Error creating Security Group: InvalidParameterValue: Cannot use reserved security group name: default**

Any idea how can it be manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

Since terraform version [0.74](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#074-september-19-2016) there is a new resource type `aws_default_security_group` which allows you to manipulate the default security group.

You can read more here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/default_security_group.html